# Solve $\cos z=2$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Solve $$\cos z=2  \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}$$

I consider $z=x+i y$, so:

$$\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x) \ \cos(iy)-\sin(iy) \ \sin(x)=\cos(x) \ \cosh(y)-i \ \sinh(y) \ \sin(x)$$

I have to satisfy this conditions:

$$\sinh(y) \ \sin(x)=0 \\ \cos(x) \ \cosh(y)=2$$

$$\sin(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=k \pi $$
$$\rvert \cos( k \pi) \rvert=1  $$

So: 
$$\cos(x) \ \cosh(y)=2$$ is impossible.

Is it correct?

Comment: Why should $\cos (x) \cosh (y) = 2$ be impossible?

Comment: Consider $\cos z= \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} = 2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentionned this is probably not the best method.

I suggest to write $$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=2.$$ This leads to an equation $$e^{2iz}-4e^{iz}+1=0$$ or $$Z^2-4Z+1=0$$ by setting $Z=e^{iz}.$

Comment: how would you solve this?

Comment: Quadratic formula

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the reason. $\cosh(y)=2$ is possible!

Answer (score 1):

There are no real solutions for $\cos z = 2$. However, there are complex solutions to this.

First, we must use Euler's formula  $$\mathrm{e}^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z,$$ where $$i = \sqrt{-1}.$$

Replacing $z$ with $-z$, we find $$\mathrm{e}^{-iz} = \cos z - i\sin z.$$ I used the even symmetry property for $\cos z$ and the odd symmetry property for $\sin z$.

Adding $\mathrm{e}^{-iz}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{iz}$ together, we find that the result is $2\cos z$, which is 4, since $\cos z$ is 2. Multiplying both sides of 
$\mathrm{e}^{iz} + \mathrm{e}^{-iz} = 4$ by $\mathrm{e}^{iz}$, we get
$$\left(\mathrm{\mathrm{e}^{iz}}\right)^{2} + 1 = 4 \mathrm{e}^{iz}.$$
Subtracting both sides by $4 \mathrm{e}^{iz}$, we get 
$$\left(\mathrm{\mathrm{e}^{iz}}\right)^{2} - 4\mathrm{e}^{iz} + 1=0,$$ which is a quadratic equation. Now, I'll spare you some time: after using the quadratic formula and substituting the coefficients of the equation into the quadratic equation, we get $ {4 \pm \sqrt{12} \over 2} $.  After rationalizing $\sqrt{12}$, and then dividing by $2$, we get $$ 2 \pm \sqrt{3}.$$
This means that $\mathrm{e}^{iz} = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}$.
Taking the natural log of both sides, we get $ iz = \ln (2 \pm \sqrt{3}) $.

Lastly, dividing both sides by $i$, we get $$ z = {\ln (2 \pm \sqrt{3}) \over i}.$$

Therefore, $$ \cos z = \cos \left({\ln (2 \pm \sqrt{3}) \over i}\right) = 2.$$

After evaluating  $\ln (2 \pm \sqrt{3})$, and when taking into consideration that dividing by i is the same as multiplying by negative i; to give you a better feel, 
$ \cos (\pm 1.31695789692i) $ is roughly 2.

Answer (score 0):

cos(x)cosh(y)=2 is impossible because by solving sin(x)sinh(y)=0, we will get y=0 and substituting (y=0) from previous equation leaves us with cos(x)=2, which is off the bounds of the sine and cosine funtions, hence it is impossible.

Comment: Use LaTeX please. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/